# How can I host my Bitcoin API on the 21 market with a Virtual IP?

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, bitcoin, virtual-ip-address

I'm trying to make my simple Pokemon API available on something other than my localhost. The API has two files, client.py and server.py. I ran the `21 market join` command and got a virtual IP. (10.244.121.0).

I tried modifying my script so that instead of the client.py requesting "http://localhost:5000/" it would request "http://10.244.121.0:5000/", but when I run the client.py I get an error when requesting that url. I'm pretty new to Python so I don't know what I need to do in order to make this API available to anyone who requests it on the `10.244.121.0` address.

client.py:

```
...
# server address
server_url = 'http://10.244.121.0/'


def name():
    id = input("Please enter a Pokemon ID: ")
    sel_url = server_url + 'name?id={0}'
    answer = requests.get(url=sel_url.format(id))
    print(answer.text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name()
```

server.py:

```
  ...
  @app.route('/name')
    @payment.required(1)
    def answer_question():

        # extract answer from client request
        id = request.args.get('id')
        url = 'http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + id

        response = requests.get(url)
        pokemonData = json.loads(response.text)
        pokemonName = pokemonData['name']
        print(pokemonName)
        return pokemonName

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

Here is the error I get when replacing the host in the `app.run` function from `0.0.0.0` to the virtual IP:

```
   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='10.244.121.0', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /name?id=1 
   (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f98d6b6e470>: 
    Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Github repo: https://github.com/LAMike310/pokedex

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `python client.py` directly, I can now use `21 buy http://10.244.121.0:5000/name?id=1` to call my API remotely.